# Powershell - How to split a string based on various characters and a 10-digit number?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following scenario where I need to split the string into various columns.  I intend to export it to a .csv, which that part of my code works, I just need help splitting the following into columns, please.

Sometimes there will be the first name and sometimes not, when there's not, I would like for it to just be blank.  How can I code this to get my result, please?

One of the main things I'm after in this is the 10 digit id, which should always be a 10 digit number.

**String:**

- 20201015\smith-1234567890-contract_application-20200418_1889
- 20201015\jones-john-0987654321-salary_contract-20200309_1642

**Desired Result:**

[image]

**Current problem with the code:**

The name 'john' is appearing in the personID column because of how the split in the $Results variable is setup.  I currently don't have a first name column in the variable, but that's what I'd like to add.  Since there are 2 dashes before the 10 digit number, I'm not sure how to do that.

```
#Get the names of the files
$InStuff = @(Get-ChildItem "\\filepath"-Name -Recurse) 
                            
#Split out path into columns
$Results = @(foreach($filepath in $InStuff)
{
  $parts = $filepath -split '-'; 
  [pscustomobject]@{"DateFirst" = $parts[0]; "PersonID" = $parts[1]; "PersonFileType" = $parts[2]; "FilePath"=$filepath }
})
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Am i correct in thinking the first field is actually the directory name the file is in?

Comment: @Theo, yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend a combination of a switch statement, with regex pattern matching and finally splitting the name (only happens if it's needed.) This will only handle two names though, but based on your description this should work fine.

```
$text = @'
20201015\smith-1234567890-contract_application-20200418_1889
20201015\jones-john-0987654321-salary_contract-20200309_1642
'@ -split "`n"

switch -Regex ($text) {
    '^(\d+)\\(.+)-(\d{10})-(.+)-(.+)' {
        $lastname,$firstname = $matches.2 -split '-'
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date      = $matches.1
            LastName  = $lastname
            FirstName = $firstname
            PersonID  = $matches.3
            FileName  = $matches.4
            DateCode  = $matches.5
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Date      : 20201015
LastName  : smith
FirstName : 
PersonID  : 1234567890
FileName  : contract_application
DateCode  : 20200418_1889

Date      : 20201015
LastName  : jones
FirstName : john
PersonID  : 0987654321
FileName  : salary_contract
DateCode  : 20200309_1642
```

You can pipe the results straight to `Export-Csv` - this is just an example, I'm sure you have other code you will insert this switch statement into.

```
$results = switch -Regex ($text) {
    '^(\d+)\\(.+)-(\d{10})-(.+)-(.+)' {
        $lastname,$firstname = $matches.2 -split '-'
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date      = $matches.1
            LastName  = $lastname
            FirstName = $firstname
            PersonID  = $matches.3
            FileName  = $matches.4
            DateCode  = $matches.5
        }
    }
}

$results | export-csv c:\temp\exporttest.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow!  What an answer, you did a great job on this!  I modified it to include my $InStuff variable and it just works.  Great job @Doug Maurer!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
^(?<Date>\d+)\\(?<lastName>\w+)(?:-(?<firstName>\w+))?-(?<personID>\d+)-(?<filename>.*)-(?<dateCode>\d+_\d+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFCPb8/2).  **Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<Date>\d+)` - one or more digits
- `\\` - a backslash
- `(?<lastName>\w+)` -  one or more word chars
- `(?:-(?<firstName>\w+))?` - an optional sequence of a `-` and then 1+ word chars
- `-(?<personID>\d+)` - `-` and 1+ digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?<filename>.*)` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?<dateCode>\d+_\d+)` - 1+ digits, `_`, 1+ digits
- `$`- end of string.

Powershell test:

```bsh
$rx='^(?<Date>\d+)\\(?<lastName>\w+)(?:-(?<firstName>\w+))?-(?<personID>\d+)-(?<filename>.*)-(?<dateCode>\d+_\d+)$'
$s='20201015\smith-1234567890-contract_application-20200418_1889'
$s -match $rx
$matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
filename                       contract_application
lastName                       smith
Date                           20201015
dateCode                       20200418_1889
personID                       1234567890
0                              20201015\smith-1234567890-contract_application-20200418_1889
```

Comment: That's a weird first name ;)  But a lovely answer none-the-less.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer on this @Wiktor, but I think you may be getting the same result issue I get.  In this particular line you selected, the first name should be blank, but it has the number in it.

Comment: @JM1 sorry, I missed that one field, fixed now.